# How to manipulate data coming from child component in parent component (Angular)?

Tags: angular, components, primeng

I have two components -*'employee-list'* and *'employee-edit'*

- `employee-list` : a parent component
- `employee-edit` : a child component

**<employee-list.component.html>**

```js
<button pButton type="button" (onClick)="openDialog()">
  <i class="pi pi-pencil" aria-label="Edit"></i>
</button>
<app-employee-edit></app-employee-edit>
```

**<employee-list.component.ts>**

```js
import { EmployeeEditComponent } from '../employee-edit/employee-edit.component';

export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {
  displayDialog: boolean = false;

  @Input()
  public employeeEdit!: EmployeeEditComponent;

  openDialog() {
    this.employeeEdit.displayDialog = true;
  }
}
```

**<employee-edit.component.html>**

```js
<p-dialog
  header="{{ employeeName }}"
  [(visible)]="displayDialog"
  [style]="{ width: '50vw' }"
  [baseZIndex]="10000"
  ><p>Employee Edit</p></p-dialog
>
```

**<employee-edit.component.ts>**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-edit',
  templateUrl: './employee-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-edit.component.scss'],
})
export class EmployeeEditComponent {
  displayDialog: boolean = false;
}
```

I want to manipulate `displayDialog`, which is boolean, so that the `employee-edit` dialog opens in another component on click by using `@Input()`.
However, it does not work as expected.

How can I manipulate the variable coming from the child component in the parent component?
Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: instead of `@Input` you have to use `@ViewChild`

Comment: Can you please be more elaborate? @DerHerrGammler

Comment: Using `@Input()` and `@Output()` to pass data between components is covered in the Angular official tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

You want to access a child component from a parent component but you try to use `@Input()` for this case, what is the wrong way. `@Input()` is used to pass data from a parent component to a child component.
If you want to use your child component in the code of the Parent Component you have to use `@ViewChild()` wich is used to get the access to manipulate the child component from the parent component:

<employee-list.component.html>

```
<button pButton type="button" (onClick)="openDialog()">
  <i class="pi pi-pencil" aria-label="Edit"></i>
</button>
<app-employee-edit #editComponent></app-employee-edit>
```

<employee-list.component.ts>

```
import { EmployeeEditComponent } from '../employee-edit/employee-edit.component';

export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('editComponent') public employeeEdit!: EmployeeEditComponent;

  openDialog() {
    this.employeeEdit.displayDialog = true;
  }
}
```

**Option 2**

Another option would be to made the `displayDialog` property in the child component to an Input and provide the property to the html tag:

<employee-list.component.html>

```
<button pButton type="button" (onClick)="openDialog()">
  <i class="pi pi-pencil" aria-label="Edit"></i>
</button>
<app-employee-edit [displayDialog]="displayDialog"></app-employee-edit>
```

<employee-list.component.ts>

```
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {
  displayDialog: boolean = false;

  openDialog() {
    this.displayDialog = true;
  }
}
```

<employee-edit.component.ts>

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-edit',
  templateUrl: './employee-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-edit.component.scss'],
})
export class EmployeeEditComponent {
  @Input() public displayDialog: boolean = false;
}
```